# After calling alfresco webcsript, Getting HTTP ERROR 504 on production but not on local and DEV

Tags: web-services, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I wrote one Java Backed webscript in alfresco to traverse all documents in one site and check some properties.
But After calling that webcsript on Production, I am Getting HTTP ERROR 504

But Same webscript is working on DEV and Local.
The reason here is there are very less documents on local and DEV. but on production there are huge number of documents present in the site.
SO its taking more time for traverse, and i am not getting my expected result on production.

SO can we increase that time out period, or is there any other way using that i can execute my webscript and get the expected result on production.

Please suggest the possible ways.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Without seeing any code, we can't tell you what's wrong with it that means it takes too long!

Comment: Try to use paging logic to return certain amount of documents. If we see your code, we can help you more.

Answer (score 2):

You must provide code if you want anything more specific than general suggestions. As Muralidharan Deenathayalan said, you should try paging in your controller.

You might also want to try using an entirely different approach. For something like this you probably don't really need a web script. If you are just checking properties, why not use [OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/) instead? It's still Java, it has paging support, and you can use it to hit the server remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved this issue by implementing Activemq Queue. But your suggestion is to good. next time i will think for using OpenCMIS also